# How to disable the Test Environment for the Pay package in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, package

I'm working on a mobile app in flutter and I'm using the Pay package. I setted up the merchant id for apple pay and the merchant info for google play but for some reason I can't find anything about disableing the test environment which is a bit of a problem because I can't launch the app like this. I need my user to be able to pay with GPay and with Apple Pay.
How can I do that?

When I go in the store from my app I need to be able to purchase a product and the payment to go through, but since the test environment is still on, the payments are only simulated, which I don't want.

Comment: The paiements are simulated while you are on the debug builds. If you do a release version it will use release configuration for stores as well. So either package your app and push a test version to your beta testers (ipa or appbundle). Or just directly test using `flutter run --release`. That should do the trick as well